# How to use function annotations to verify function call types

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, type-hinting

I recently just discovered there's a thing called function annotation but I'm not very sure of how to use it. This is what I have so far:

```
def check_type(f):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        counter=0
        for arg, type in zip(args, f.__annotations__.items()):
            if not isinstance(arg, type[1]):
                msg = 'Not the valid type'
                raise ValueError(msg)
            counter+=1

        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

@check_type
def foo(a: int, b: list, c: str): #a must be int, b must be list, c must be str
    print(a,b,c)

foo(12, [1,2], '12') #This works

foo(12, 12, 12) #This raises a value error just as I wanted to

foo(a=12, b=12, c=12) #But this works too:(
```

As you can see, I'm trying to check the types of `a`,`b` and `c` using annotations and a decorator and that raises `ValueError` if it's not the right type. It works fine when I dont use keyword arguments when calling. But if I used keyword arguments, the types don't get checked. I'm trying to make it work but I had no luck.

My code doesn't support keyword argument. Because I don't have anything that checks that. Nor I have any idea on how to check it. Here's where I need help.

I also did it this way:

```
def check_type(f):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        for name, type in f.__annotations__.items():
            if not isinstance(kwargs[name], type):
                msg = 'Not the valid type'
                raise ValueError(msg)

        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

#But now they have to be assigned using keyword args
#so only foo(a=3,b=[],c='a') works foo(3,[],'a') results in a keyerror
#How can I combine them?
```

Comment: I think the easiest way would probably be to use the `inspect.Signature` class. It has a `bind` method that parses the arguments and brings them to a normalised form which you can then easily check for compliance.More specifically it returns a `BoundArguments` instance which as  an `arguments` attribute that you can use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Paul suggested, it is best to use the `bind` method of `Signature` objects (located in `inspect`) to bind the `*args` and `**kwargs` that are to be provided to `f` and then check if the type matches:

```
from inspect import signature
from typing import get_type_hints

def check_range(f):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        counter=0
        # use get_type_hints instead of __annotations__
        annotations = get_type_hints(f)
        # bind signature to arguments and get an 
        # ordered dictionary of the arguments
        b = signature(f).bind(*args, **kwargs).arguments            
        for name, value in b.items():
            if not isinstance(value, annotations[name]):
                msg = 'Not the valid type'
                raise ValueError(msg)
            counter+=1

        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

Your first case was actually succeeding randomly. `dict`s have a random order in Python `< 3.6` that will most likely change when you fire-up the Python interpreter again, that means the `zip`ping you do isn't deterministic.

Instead of iterating through `f.__annotations__`, grab it via `get_type_hints` and then, by getting the names and values through `b.items()` (which is an OrderedDict and guarantees order) index it with `name`.